# Why element.type on an array of radio or checkbox buttons returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

I'm facing a very strange situation here. Let's say I have a form with three input elements of type **radio**, just like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="donor" value="" />Heart
    <input type="radio" name="organ" value="10" />Heart
    <input type="radio" name="organ" value="20" checked="checked" />Lungs
    <input type="radio" name="organ" value="30" />Kidney    
</form>
```

and I thought this line

```
alert("input type: " + document.forms[0].organ.type);
```

would return type **radio** instead of **undefined**. Though, this one

```
alert("input type: " + document.forms[0].organ[0].type);
```

returns type **radio** and of course it's not what I want. You may see the sorcery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6UDjM/).

Does anyone know what's going on?

**1st UPDATE**

The same thing will occur if we deal with checkboxes, which means that element type on an array of radios or checkboxes buttons cannot be determined without specifying an index.

In other words, this snippet

```
var i, form = document.forms[0], fields = ['donor', 'organ'];

for(i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    switch(form[fields[i]].type) {
        case 'radio':
            alert('(a) - I can beat up Chuck Norris');
            // anyway, no one hears this :)
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            break;
        case 'text':
            alert('(a) - Chuck Norris is unbeatable');
            break;
    }
}
```

won't behave as one may expect. So, I guess, looping through the form elements is the only solution left. Well, it's not - check the 2nd update.

```
for(i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    switch(form.elements[i].type) {
        case 'radio': 
            alert('(b) - Nobody can beat up Chuck Norris');
            // now, check if this element is in fields[] 
            // and do something  
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            break;
        case 'text':
            alert('(b) - Chuck Norris is unbeatable');
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HLPd/).

**2nd UPDATE**

In a meantime I found a pretty simple way to access and query form elements looping through `fields` object (in my case) and not looping through all elements.

```
var form = document.forms[0], fields = ['donor', 'organ'];

for (var key in fields) {
    switch(form[key].type){
        case 'select-one':
            break;
        case 'select-multiple':
            break;
        case 'checkbox': // we are dealing with a single checbox button 
            break;
        case 'text': case 'textarea': case 'hidden': case 'password':
            break;
        default:
            if(form[key][0].type == radio' || form[key][0].type == radio' == 'checkbox') {
                // we're dealing with an array of radio or checkbox buttons, otherwise
            }else{
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't! Radio's are somewhat special form control elements, as they are allowed multiple instances with the same name. `form.inputRadio` will refer to a collection of input[type=radio] elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret can be seen if you add this line:

```
alert(document.forms[0].organ.toString());
```

and you'll see that it creates a `RadioNodeList`, which is an array-like structure.

Because all related radio buttons have the same name, yet are different elements, you have to access them in this way to set the status.

If you truly *MUST* access them without using array syntax `[0]`, you could give each radio button a unique ID:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="radio_1" name="organ" value="10" />Heart
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="organ" value="20" checked="checked" />Lungs
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="organ" value="30" />Kidney
</form>

<script>
    alert("input type: " + document.forms[0].organ[0].type);

    alert(document.forms[0].organ.toString());

    alert("input type: " + document.getElementById("radio_1").type);
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my problem but at least you confirmed my doubts. And thanks for the `toString()` tip :)